# System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm having a problem but I don't know exactly why.

```
namespace RCSv1._0
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm()); // The exception throws here
        }
    }
}
```

This error doesn't happen when the program starts to run, it happens when activate 1 of 4 these events, and the exception occurs randomly (it could happen in any of 4 events)

```
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            homeInputPanel = new HomeInputPanel(pnlHomeInput);
            nuclideInputPanel = new NuclideInputPanel(pnlNuclideInput);
            modelsInputPanel = new ModelsInputPanel(pnlModelsInput);
            kineticsInputPanel = new KineticsInputPanel(pnlKineticsInput);
            doseOutputPanel = new DoseOutputPanel(pnlDoseOutput);
            pnlHomeInput.BringToFront();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void BtnNuclideInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawColourMouseHoverMenuButton(btnNuclideInput);
            pnlNuclideInput.BringToFront();
        }

        private void BtnModelsInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawColourMouseHoverMenuButton(btnModelsInput);
            pnlModelsInput.BringToFront();
        }

        private void BtnKineticsInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawColourMouseHoverMenuButton(btnKineticsInput);
            pnlKineticsInput.BringToFront();
        }

        private void BtnHomeInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawColourMouseHoverMenuButton(btnHomeInput);
            pnlHomeInput.BringToFront();
            UserData.HumanAge = modelsInputPanel.ReturnHumanAgeOption();
        }

        public void DrawColourMouseHoverMenuButton(BunifuThinButton2 btn)
        {
            btnNuclideInput.IdleFillColor = Color.White;
            btnNuclideInput.IdleForecolor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btnModelsInput.IdleFillColor = Color.White;
            btnModelsInput.IdleForecolor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btnKineticsInput.IdleFillColor = Color.White;
            btnKineticsInput.IdleForecolor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btnDose.IdleFillColor = Color.White;
            btnDose.IdleForecolor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btnHomeInput.IdleFillColor = Color.White;
            btnHomeInput.IdleForecolor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btn.IdleFillColor = Color.SeaGreen;
            btn.IdleForecolor = Color.White;
        }
```

I don't know exactly why this error occurs. Can anybody explain?

The call stack is RCSv1.0.exe!RCSv1._0.Program.Main() Line 19
    at D:\NHHSchool\RCSProgram\RCSProgram\RCSv1.0\Program.cs(19)

Comment: Did you try to debug this? What is the call stack when the exception occurs?

Comment: I've just add what you said to the topic

Comment: In Visual Studio (if you are using it) select Debug->Exceptions menu to open the Exceptions dialog. Use Find button to look for ArgumentException and then mark its Thrown checkbox. This will cause your debugger to stop at the moment the exception is thrown instead of stopping when it is unhandled. Then you will be able to see exactly what argument caused the problem. I assume something is uninitialized when your event is activated, but it's only a guess.